# Correct way to create Rails-4-expected table and column names for HABTM with migration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I need a HABTM join table for `item_ones` and `item_twos`, but I can't seem to get the migration results to match Rails's expectations.  If I do this:

```
create_join_table :item_ones, :item_twos do |t|
   ...
end
```

(...which is what `rails g migration CreateJoinTableOneTwo item_one item_two` generates...)

..then it creates a table named `item_ones_item_twos`, but Rails will be looking for `item_ones_twos` (because in 4.0, it [factors out common prefixes](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4649294)).  If I do this:

```
create_join_table :item_ones, :twos do |t|
  ...
end
```

Then it creates the right table, but the second foreign key is named `two_id` instead of `item_two_id`.

So is there any way to get this right other than e.g. manually specifying a `:table_name`?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, Rails would expect a join table name of `<first model>s_<second model>s` (eg. `assemblies_parts`) for any HABTM join tables. However, because ItemOne and ItemTwo have the same prefix (Item), Rails shortens the required table name to `item_ones_twos`.

You will need to specify the `table_name` option, as detailed here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-join-table

Comment: Given that Rails factors out the common prefix, shouldn't `create_join_table` do likewise?

Comment: I don't know, but it doesn't. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5a31d6340f0ee9f3ff071206b114c0d0a5e52b8e/activerecord/lib/active_record/migration/join_table.rb#L11 Maybe it should be submitted as a patch.